# vscode won't show suggestion no matter what I do

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Visual studio does not show suggestions.
for instance Ive mongodb and i'm exporting two things, mongoConnect, and getDb.

```
const mongodb = require("mongodb");
const MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;

let _db;

const mongoConnect = (callback) => {
  MongoClient.connect("mongodb://0.0.0.0:27017")
    .then((client) => {
      console.log("Connected!");
      _db = client.db("shop");
      // callback();
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
      throw err;
    });
};

const getDb = () => {
  if (_db) {
    return _db;
  }
  throw "No database found!";
};

exports.mongoConnect = mongoConnect;
exports.getDb = getDb;
```

here calling methods on _db after it is assigned a value shows all the properties that it have but

when I use it like this in some other file
const db = getDb();

it doesn't show properties that this database variable have like in the database file with _id variable. but works properly.

```
{
  "editor.suggestSelection": "recentlyUsed",
  "vsintellicode.modify.editor.suggestSelection": "automaticallyOverrodeDefaultValue",
  "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
  "workbench.colorCustomizations": {},
  "liveServer.settings.donotShowInfoMsg": true,
  "workbench.sideBar.location": "right",
  "editor.cursorBlinking": "phase",
  "files.autoSave": "afterDelay",
  "files.autoSaveDelay": 3,
  "editor.fontFamily": "Fira Code",
  "editor.fontLigatures": true,
  "liveServer.settings.donotVerifyTags": true,
  "javascriptBooster.formattingOptions": {},
  "typescript.validate.enable": false,
  "prettier.embeddedLanguageFormatting": "off",
  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
  "prettier.quoteProps": "preserve",
  "tabnine.experimentalAutoImports": true,
  "bracketPairColorizer.consecutivePairColors": [
    "()",
    "[]",
    "{}",
    //gold, orchid, lightskyblue
    ["Orange", "Amber", "Gold"],
    "Red"
  ],
  "bracketPairColorizer.colorMode": "Independent",
  "vsicons.dontShowNewVersionMessage": true,
  "files.exclude": {
    "**/.classpath": true,
    "**/.project": true,
    "**/.settings": true,
    "**/.factorypath": true
  },
  "security.workspace.trust.untrustedFiles": "open",
  "[dart]": {
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "editor.formatOnType": true,
    "editor.rulers": [80],
    "editor.selectionHighlight": false,
    "editor.suggest.snippetsPreventQuickSuggestions": false,
    "editor.suggestSelection": "first",
    "editor.tabCompletion": "onlySnippets",
    "editor.wordBasedSuggestions": false,
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "Dart-Code.dart-code",
    "editor.wordWrap": "wordWrapColumn",
    "diffEditor.wordWrap": "on",
    "editor.wordWrapColumn": 90
  },
  "dart.hotReloadOnSave": "manual",
  "dartImport.fixOnSave": true,
  "workbench.colorTheme": "GitHub Light Default",
  "terminal.integrated.fontFamily": "monospace",
  "dart.showInspectorNotificationsForWidgetErrors": false,
  "editor.codeLensFontFamily": "Fira Code Light",
  "editor.fontWeight": "normal",
  "files.associations": {
    "*.java": "java",
    "*.js": "javascriptreact"
  },
  "dart.flutterCreatePlatforms": ["android", "windows", "web"],
  "[markdown]": {
    "editor.wordWrap": "on",
    "editor.wordWrapColumn": 80,
    "diffEditor.wordWrap": "inherit"
  },
  "editor.tabSize": 2,
  "workbench.iconTheme": "vscode-icons",
  "window.menuBarVisibility": "toggle",
  "workbench.layoutControl.enabled": false,
  "workbench.editor.tabSizing": "shrink",
  "editor.fontSize": 16,
  "window.commandCenter": true,
  "[javascriptreact]": {
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
  },
  "explorer.confirmDragAndDrop": false,
  "editor.minimap.enabled": false,
  "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {},
  "fluttergpt.apiKey": "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",
  "chat-gpt.lang": "en",
  "workbench.startupEditor": "none",
  "eslint.codeAction.disableRuleComment": {
    "location": "sameLine"
  }
}
```

what I've tried

1. updated the builtin typescript and javascript extension
2. installed eslint extension
3. installed intellicode extension

Comment: that's a lot of settings. see the instructions on providing a [mre]

Comment: If i knew where in the settings the problem is, I would've solved it myself.  Or if i knew how to produce it. Idk, that's why I've posted all this.

Comment: There's such a thing as an [extension bisect](//code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2021/02/16/extension-bisect). In a similar vein, you can pretty easily do a setting bisect manually.